# Can't go 1 step left/right in reel plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-reel

So I use this [jQuery Reel](http://reel360.org/reel) plugin as 3D slideshow on my website. I also want to provide manual stepping, but it gets bugged. Here is the simple code I made to step left or right:

```
$(function() {
    $('.left').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.reel').trigger('stepLeft');
    });
    $('.right').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.reel').trigger('stepRight');
    });
});
```

If you use `.left` or `.right` element, it will step by two steps. When you have about 200 images, you won't see the difference, but when you have about 10 images, the it is so obvious. Try it at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5ftkjag/).

Comment: Can you supply a 'bugged' fiddle also for comparison?

Comment: jsFiddle I pointed in the question is also 'bugged'. Look at these: 1 step with mouse drag (http://prnt.sc/eyah6g) and 1 step by element click (http://prnt.sc/eyah9k)